# Como modificar uma lista no global scope utilizando uma função? Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, lista

```
def lsum(x):
    res = []
    for i in x:
        res.append(x+1)
    L = res
L = [1,2,4]
lsum(L)
print(L)
```

Como posso modificar o código acima sem usar `global L` para que print("L") "retorne" [2,3,5]? Ou seja, quero modificar a lista L dentro da função e levar as modificações para o scope global. Eu sou novo no python então agradeço respostas simples.

Answer (score 2):

Basta retornar o valor e atribuir à variável L novamente:

```
def lsum(x):
    res = []
    for i in x:
        res.append(i+1)              # <- Aqui é i+1, não x+1
    return res                       # <- Retornando o valor

L = [1,2,4]
L = lsum(L)                          # <- Atribuindo o valor retornado a L
print(L)
```

Você pode ainda gerar o mesmo resultado utilizando compressão de listas:

```
def lsum(x):
    return [i+1 for i in x]

L = [1,2,4]
L = lsum(L)
print(L)
```

Ou ainda funções *lambda*:

```
lsum = lambda x: [i+1 for i in x]

L = [1,2,4]
L = lsum(L)
print(L)
```

Indiquei as três formas para que possa servir de direção para estudos futuros. Busque sobre materiais de algoritmos antes de iniciar o estudo em uma linguagem, visto que, aparentemente, falta-lhe muitos conceitos básicos.

> A linguagem de programação é como uma ferramenta de trabalho: um meio de se fazer arte nas mãos de quem sabe utilizá-la ou uma arma nas mãos de quem não sabe.